# When is an I-864 required when filing an I-485?

Tags: usa, immigration

According to the [*"Checklist of Required Initial Evidence for Immediate Relatives and Family-Based Preference Form I-485 Applicants"*](https://www.uscis.gov/i-485Checklist), and I-864 **MAY** be required,

> - Form I-864, Affidavit of Support (if required);

Since this is "The Checklist" for an I-485, how do I know if it is required or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [I-485 instructions](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-485instr.pdf), page 12, it describes whether I-864 Affidavit of Support is required. Basically, I-864 is required for almost all family-based cases, as well as in the small percentage of employment-based cases where the employer is 5% or more owned by the beneficiary's relative. It is not needed in other categories. [7 USCIS-PM A.6(D)(2)](https://www.uscis.gov/policy-manual/volume-7-part-a-chapter-6#S-D-2) and [9 FAM 601.14-3](https://fam.state.gov/fam/09FAM/09FAM060114.html#M601_14_3) have more information on which categories are required to file I-864.